# Dynamically setting ng-model is breaking

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I have a directive HTML template like this:

`textinput.html`

```
<label for="{{name}}">{{label}}</label>
<input type="{{type}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" id="{{name}}" ng-model="{{name}}">
```

The label is outputting correctly, however everything inside of the input field is outputing as static `{{varname}}`

If I remove the ng-model like this:

```
<input type="{{type}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" id="{{name}}">
```

It outputs the variables correctly, but the moment I place the ng-model in and dynamically assign it a value, it breaks the entire input.

Why is this happening?

My goal is to be able to create simple 1 line text inputs which I can mass change with the directive, like so:

```
<textinput name="username" label="Username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username"></textinput>
```

Comment: How are you planning on accessing the model once it's set from within your directive? You won't really know what the model on the $scope is called if it's something different each time.

Comment: I'm trying to access it through a directive call like this:
`<textinput name="username" label="Username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username"></textinput>`

Comment: try setting ng-model="name"

Comment: @Hoyen if you look at the example template above, the value of the name="username" so the variable {{name}} should output as `username` which it does, unless it's placed within ng-model

Comment: ng-model is a angular directive. And so you don't need the curly braces for it to evaluate the value of 'name'. The other attributes are non-angular directives and are HTML attributes, so you need to use the curly braces for angular to evaluate them.

Comment: The string "Name" needs to be dynamic, how can I have it be dynamic?

Comment: The name will be picked up from your custom directive that sets name="username".

Comment: just do: <input type="{{type}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" id="{{name}}" ng-model="name" name="{{name}}"> - or even better do a plunkr or something with your example - personally I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: @sirrocco I'm trying to get this: `<textinput name="username" label="Username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username"></textinput>` to output the textinput.html everything is working except for the ng-model declaration, there may be a better way to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, you have to pass the ng-model through using 2 way binding like this:

```
<textinput type="email" name="userEmail" ng-model="userEmail" placeholder="Email Address..." label="Email"></textinput>
```

-

```
app.directive('textinput', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        label:'@label',
        placeholder:'@placeholder',
        name: '@name',
        type: '@type',
        ngModel: '=ngModel'
    },
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: 'directives/textinput.html'
};
});
```

Now within the template HTML file you can map properties without the `{{ }}` which works with ng-model.

example:

```
<label for="{{name}}">{{label}}</label>
<input type="{{type}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" id="{{name}}" ng-model="ngModel">
```

Now it'll be super easy to quickly generate re-usable form code.